# CakePHP 2.0: CakeEmail frustration

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In Cake 1.3, the EmailComponent did what it should do. The new Cake Email class in 2.0 turned out to be a frustration....No emails sent, No errors....vague documentation...

I have tried all possible variants, tried it with my SMTP, Mail() and Gmail, nothing happens. Hereby my latest attempt:

Controller snippet:

```
//on top of page
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');


//in method
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->template('contact_email')
->emailFormat('text')
->to('my@gmail.com')
->from('other@gmail.com')
->send();
```

Email.php Config file:

class EmailConfig {

```
//It also does not work with a constructor

public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => '***',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

Can someone please post WORKING code for the Email Class. Many thanks

Comment: "Nothing happens" is no real error description. Is debug set to 2?

Comment: Debug is set to 2. Once I submit my form, I receive a success message.....an email is never send.

Comment: -1. Please be a little more professional with future questions; nonconstructive criticism, CAPS, and give me working code don't make for good questions.

Comment: It is really frustrating.. $Email = new CakeEmail($s) where $s has all email configuration variable does not work. $Email->config($s) does not work either.

Comment: Oh well! I missed the "Transport" in my configuration setting created dynamically. Added if(!isset($s['transport'])) $s['transport'] = 'Smtp'; to it and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have to load your config from Config/email.php explicitly, it is not loaded automatically, not even the default config:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->config('default');

//or in constructor::
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
```

Comment: Not anymore since CakePHP 2.7 where the 'default' config is loaded automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you should use this:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my email config file . I didnt do any change here

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'Admin <no-reply@example.com>',       
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

}
```

This is how i send the mail

```
$email    = new CakeEmail();

$result   = $email->template('welcome')
              ->emailFormat('text')
              ->to($NewUser['email'])
              ->from('admin@example.com')
              ->send();
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks Web Developer. I did all you said, I see a dump and added the correct parameters for my mail server (That work with the old Mail Component), still nothing is sent. Are you able to email with this script? I receive no error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Web developer, this turned out to be the issue