# Cakephp mock Email Utility

Tags: unit-testing, email, cakephp

i'm a little stuck trying to test my users-controller in cakephp,
i have an action wich sends an email to a certain email address.
The email utility works, no problem whatsoever.

I want to mock the email utility so that when i test the action (with "testAction"),
no email will be sent.
I already searched all over stackoverflow and tried a lot of solutions, the current code is like follows:

UsersController:

```
    /**
 *  Get Email Utility, use method so that unit testing is possible
 *  @return object
 */
public function _getEmailer()
{
    return new CakeEmail();
}


public function lostPassword()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $email = $this->request->data['User']['email'];

        $this->User->recursive = -1;
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('email' => $email)));

        if(!$user)
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error: user not found');
            return $this->render();
        }

        $recoverTrials = $this->User->Recover->find('count', array('conditions' => array('email' => $email)));
        if($recoverTrials > 3)
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('message.recover-too-many'));
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }

        // Generate random key to reset password
        $key = md5(microtime().rand());

        $data = array('user_id' => $user['User']['id'],
                      'key' => $key,
                      'active' => 1,
                      'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        if(!$this->User->Recover->save($data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error while sending the recovery-mail');
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }

        $this->Email = $this->_getEmailer();
        $this->Email->emailFormat('html');
        $this->Email->to($email);
        $this->Email->subject('Password recover');
        $this->Email->replyTo('noreply@domain.com');
        $this->Email->from(array('noreply@domain.com' => 'Sender ID'));
        $this->Email->template('recover');
        $this->Email->viewVars(array('key' => $key));   // Set variables for template

        try
        {
            $this->Email->send();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error while sending the recovery-mail');
            return $this->render();
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash('The recovery mail with instructions to reset your password has been sent. Please note that the link will only remain active for 2 hours.');
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

And my test class looks like (excerpt):

```
public function testPostLostPassword()
{
    $this->Controller = $this->generate('Users', array(
        'methods' => array(
            '_getEmailer'
        ),
        'components' => array('Security')
    ));

    $emailer = $this->getMock('CakeEmail', array(
        'to',
        'emailFormat',
        'subject',
        'replyTo',
        'from',
        'template',
        'viewVars',
        'send'
    ));

    $emailer->expects($this->any())
            ->method('send')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $this->Controller->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('_getEmailer')
                    ->will($this->returnValue($emailer));

    Correct email
    $data = array('User' => array('email' => 'me@domain.com'));
    $result = $this->testAction('/lostPassword', array('method' => 'post',
                                                             'data' => $data,
                                                             'return' => 'contents'));
}
```

What am i doing wrong? The Email utility still sends out the email to my address, even though i mocked it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, works fine for me. Maybe you should show all of the relevant code, not just a broken snippet. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i inserted the complete methods into the code.
Ps.: Cake version is 2.4.2

Comment: This question is related, and answered well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712865/use-a-different-email-config-during-unit-testing-in-cakephp