# CakeEmail not sending variable

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can't get the content of email. `$content` variable are not populated.

`$this->request->data['message']` come from a textarea input which allow HTML.

Controller

```
debug($this->request->data['mensagem']); // Output: <p>\n\ttssseste<\/p>\n

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->from(array('noreply@domain.com' => 'System'));
$email->to($this->AuthExtended->user('email'));
$email->subject(__('Sample email'));
$email->template('test_email');
$email->viewVars(array('content' => $this->request->data['mensagem']));
$email->send();
```

view/Emails/html/test_email.ctp

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

I get the email but without content. If I change `test_email.ctp` to:

```
Foo <?php echo $content; ?>
```

I get only `Foo` instead of `Foo` plus `$content`.

**UPDATE**

After `$email->viewVars(array('content' => $this->request->data['mensagem']));` I tried to debug with `debug($email->viewVars());` which show my "posted" variable, but, nothing inside the views.

```
array(
    'content' => 'foo bar here'
)
```

Comment: Which view sends the data to the controller? How do you create the `mensagem` input?

Comment: From a textarea from form. Content is HTML.

Comment: Have you tried setting `content` manually: `array('content' => 'Bar')`?

Comment: Tell me how do you create that textarea (any helper?). You send it by post? Do you create the form with the form helper?

Comment: @Steve, the form are correct. Inside the controller, if I debug `$this->request->data['mensagem']` I get `<p>\n\ttssseste<\/p>\n`.

Comment: @vanneto Yes, have tried and don't work as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to set a normal variable like just a number or a text without HTML tags?

Comment: @Steve Yes. Tried a lot of things, but, the problem appears to be in `viewVars` which are not setting the variable properly.

Comment: Do you have the debug set to 3? Don't you see any message of "Undefined variable:"?

Comment: @Steve set to `2` which is the highest available debug level. No. I am sure I have not "wrong codes". I and my team revised the code a lot but whe can't see where are the problem.

Comment: Your code does seem correct. Have you tried looking at the CakeEmail class? The docs are not always perfect. I also found this in the docs: new CakeEmail('templated'), although it doesn't explain if the 'templated' param is required or not.

Comment: There is also some talk here that the config method should be called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342139/cakephp-2-0-cakeemail-frustration?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

For sending templated email use this :

$email->template('test_email_view', 'test_email');

here test_email_view is view file place it in app/View/Emails/html/test_email_view.ctp
and put here the code that you want to view in your email body message

and test_email is you layout file app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/test_email.ctp
and put echo $this->fetch('content');